# Meaning of a battery being 2.5 V

Tags: potential, voltage, conventions, batteries

So this is a question with which I have been stuck for a while and it all revolves around the concept of volt.

I have posted a LOT of questions on physics forums while trying to understand the concept of volt and potential difference. This is hopefully going to be the last one.

What do you exactly mean when you say that a battery is **2.5 V**. I know that it says that the potential difference between the 2 terminals of the battery is **2.5 V**  but then what is the potential of the 2 ends of the battery? Is there a unit of potential and not just potential difference?

Also **volt = work/charge** but how can **work/charge** express the difference of potentials across the 2 terminals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Volt** is a name for the unit **Joule-per-Coulomb** (energy-per-charge).

- 2.5 volt means 2.5 Joules per Coulomb.
- A 2.5 volt battery means that there is a difference of 2.5 Joules per Coulomb from one terminal to the other.
- The actual values (of electric potential) are not known (and are not important); they could be 3 volts at one terminal and 5.5 volts at the other. But the difference in electric potential (voltage) is still 2.5 volts.

The unit of **electric potential** and of **electric potential difference** (also called **voltage**) are *the same*, namely the volt. A difference $\Delta V=V_2-V_1$ is just a subtraction and doesn't change the units.

> how can work/charge express the difference of potentials across the 2 terminals?

Charges want to stay at the point of lowest possible potential. That is thus the low-potential terminal. The battery must *do work* to move a charge from the low-potential terminal to the high-potential terminal. It must force the charge to move against the repulsion force that the charge experiences from this high-potential terminal.

The work added from the battery is there the energy that turns out to be stored as the charge is finally moved. When the charge then moves (through a circuit) to the other low-potential terminal again, all the stored energy (which equaled the work done by the battery to lift it in the first place) is then spent. The battery must then do work on this charge one more time to again move it to the high-potential terminal.

> How can you assign a joule/coulomb value to every point in the circuit?

You can do that just as you can do it to a book on a shelf. It has a certain amount of (gravitational) potential energy assigned to that specific height over the surface.

In the same way, charge is being repelled a lot from the high-potential terminal. The further it moves away from this terminal, the more the potential drops - all other points have other potentials, decreases along the circuit. This is similar to the book falling from the shelf, decreases the (gravitational) potential energy as it falls, since that stored energy is now gradually being "spent" to make it fall. Every point during the falls is associated with another amount of stored potential energy.

Comment: so what do we mean when we say that it is a 2.5 volt battery?

Comment: @Adi The unit **Joule-per-Coulomb** (energy per charge) is called **volt**. 2.5 volt means 2.5 Joules per Coulomb. A 2.5 volt battery means that there is a difference of 2.5 Joules per Coulomb from one terminal to the other. The *actual values* (of electric potential) are not important; they could be 3 volts at one terminal and 5.5 volts at the other. But the *difference* in electric potential (voltage) is still 2.5 volts.

Comment: awesome answer, but I still don't get the concept of **electric potential**. How can you assign a **joule/coulomb** value to every point in the circuit?

Comment: @Adi I have now rewritten the answer, since I can see from your question that you actually do understand the basics of the potential but ask about the concept of voltage for a battery.

Comment: @Adi Your last question in the comments is added to the answer. Every point in an electric circuit is associated with (electric) potential energy, just like every point up until a shelf is associated with (gravitational) potential energy for a book, while it falls from the shelf.

Comment: so, lemme get this clear- a battery has 2 ends, with the same charge, say negative. One end has more negative charge than the other end. The electrons from the end which has more negative charge want to go to the end which has less negative charge. For this the battery would have to do work to move the electrons. The work does by the battery would be maximum at the terminal with more negative charge(the potential here will be the potential of the terminal) as the electron is repelling a lot and it will keep decreasing as the electron reaches the other terminal. --TO BE CONTINUED--

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45262/discussion-between-adi-and-steeven).